# How i can convert this mysql statement to hql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

How i can convert this mysql statement to hql

```
    select invisit, notinVisit
    FROM(
    select COUNT(*) as invisit  from consultations cons join patients p 
    on cons.patient_id = p.id
    where cons.datefin > now()) as A
    JOIN 
    ( select COUNT(*) as notinVisit from consultations cons join patients p 
    on cons.patient_id = p.id
    where cons.datefin < now()) as B
```

my try was

```
"select com.organ.project.service.DTO.PatientsByInConsultationDTO(invisit, notinVisit)\n" +
            "FROM(\n" +
            "select COUNT(*) as invisit  from Consultation cons join Patient p \n" +
            "on cons.patient.id = p.id\n" +
            "where cons.datefin > now()) as A\n" +
            "JOIN \n" +
            "( select COUNT(*) as notinVisit from Consultation cons join Patient p \n" +
            "on cons.patient.id = p.id\n" +
            "where cons.datefin < now()) as B\n"
```

but i got this error:

```
 ...org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 2, column 5...
```

turned out that hql does not support subqueries

**ps:** i need the **invisit**, **notinVisit** props as constructor params to return an object containing the result

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
select new com.organ.project.service.DTO.PatientsByInConsultationDTO(
       sum(case when cons.datefin > now() then 1 else 0 end) as invisit,
       sum(case when cons.datefin < now() then 1 else 0 end) as notinVisit) 
from Consultation cons join Patient p on cons.patient.id = p.id
group by cons.id
```